# How do you integrate a string into a javascript function name?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I'm a php guy who knows pretty much nothing about JS, so please go easy on me ;-)

So basically, I have a page with 4 iframes in it. In some cases, I need links to change two iframes at the same time. So far, I'd been using this script which I'd found online:

```
<script language="javascript">
function loadTwo(iframe1URL, iframe2URL)
    {
    parent.main.location.href=iframe1URL;
    parent.right.location.href=iframe2URL;
    }
</script>
```

This was working great.

However, I'm now facing a situation where instead of changing the 'main' and 'right' iframes, I need to modify 'left' and 'main'. I do need to keep the above too for all the other cases.

So, I wrote this:

```
<script language="javascript">
var jssec = "<?php echo $section;?>";
var jslet = "<?php echo $flett;?>";

if(jssec == 'showlist' && jslet != '')
    {
    var panel1 = 'left';
    var panel2 = 'main';
    }
else
    {
    var panel1 = 'main';
    var panel2 = 'right';
    }

function loadTwo(iframe1URL, iframe2URL)
    {
    parent.panel1.location.href=iframe1URL;
    parent.panel2.location.href=iframe2URL;
    }
</script>
```

The first part works fine. But the function itself no longer works. I'm guessing I'm not integrating the strings correctly.

I've tried googling this but the results I'm finding are for slightly different cases, like when the string contains the function's name, which isn't quite what I have here...

So how can I get panel1 & panel2 to work within this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array notation:

```
 parent[panel1].location.href=iframe1URL;
       ^------^
```

This lets `panel1` be seen as a variable, instead of a "key" name. e.g. these two are identical in terms of execution:

```
 parent['panel1']
 parent.panel1
```

Comment: [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. This does *seem* to solve the issue, however I'm now running into a secondary problem where in some cases I'm getting unexpected results (ie. a link opening in the wrong iframes)... It might be unrelated to this though and possibly caused by something else in the code, not yet sure at this point, still digging...

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue it would seem!

Be sure to declare the vars outside of the functions.

```
//declare them here!!
var panel1;
var panel2;

if (blah) {
    panel1 = "something";
    panel2 = "somethingelse";
} else {
    //other option
}

//continue code
```

Initialized variables will just be null buckets until you put something in them, but from a language that accepts negative array indices, I don't think this should be surprising :P

The function should then be able to read them. If it can't, pass them through the function's parameters like you did with the other data.

Comment: panel1 and panel2 were already declared outside functions; loadTwo() should be able to access them just fine.